# Prove that in a basis of matrix $n \times n$ there exist al least two that doesn't commute.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $n>1$ and $B$ be a basis for the vectorial space of matrices $n \times n$ with real coefficients. Prove that exist at least two matrices that doesn't commute.

I tried to do it for contradiction, suppose that every matrix commute with each other, then if $C$ is a linear combination of $B$ we have
$$C= \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_{k} B_{k}$$
and for $B_{j} \in B$
$$B_{j}C =B_{j} \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_{k} B_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_{k} B_{j} B_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_{k} B_{k}B_{j}= CB_{j}$$
so, for every matrix in $B$ they commute with any matrix in the vectorial space.

Can you help me?

Comment: You can continue your argument further: since for all matrices $C$, $CB_j = B_jC$ for all $j = 1, 2, \ldots, n$, the same argument gives $CD = DC$ for all matrices $C, D$ also. Now choose your favorite non-commuting matrices $C, D$ for a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems your commentor OXLR has it:  the point is that otherwise you can prove that all the matrices commute.  But, of course,  this is false (unless  $n=1$).